# Web service to get the GPS Coordinates

Tags: web-services, gps, coordinates

I'm developing an web application (jsp/strtus2) which requires the GPS coordinates of a place. What I want to know is, whether there are any free web services that I can get GPS coordinates of a place by passing address or zip code to the server.

Thanks in advance,
Nuwan

Answer (score 3):

[Yahoo's Geocoder](http://developer.yahoo.com/maps/rest/V1/geocode.html) is easy to use.  Basically change a few query strings and it outputs an easy to parse xml file.

Google's had a few issues in our area with the coordinates being returned being incredibly inaccurate at times.  Yahoo tends to actually land on the street in question, but probably wont hit the parcel itself.

That said, just note these services aren't going to be the most accurate.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Bing Maps](http://www.microsoft.com/maps/developers/) or [Google Geolocation](http://code.google.com/apis/gears/api_geolocation.html) to do this. Bing has the pleasant ability to tie into native .NET namespaces.

Answer (score 0):

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/index.html

this is the link to  the geocoding service by google