# Verify user input location string is a valid geographic location?

Tags: geolocation, geocoding, google-geocoding-api

I'm accepting a user input which is supposed to be a geographic location. I would like to validate that what the user has entered describes a location--e.g., postal code, airport code, street address, city name, etc.

The obvious answer is to use the [Google Geocode API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#GeocodingRequests) to do a request for the user's input and see if I get any results.) However the geocode ToS forbids this:

> ...the Geocoding API may only be used in conjunction with a Google map; geocoding results without displaying them on a map is prohibited.

Does anyone know of alternatives?

Comment: There are some alternatives listed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9960844/is-there-way-to-do-batch-geocoding-get-lat-lon-by-address-and-vice-versa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yahoo also has a [geolocation API](http://developer.yahoo.com/geo/geoplanet/guide/yql-tables.html#geo-places) which has a less-restrictive TOS. By querying for a location, if you receive a non-`null` result set then you know its a valid place.

```
# A query for New York...
http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20%2a%20from%20geo.places%20where%20text='New+York'&format=json
# Results in a response
{"query":{"count":10,"created":"2013-01-11T18:40:32Z","lang":"en-US","results":{"place":[... places ... ] }}}
```

whereas

```
# A query for junk
http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20%2a%20from%20geo.places%20where%20text='kqpo234xk'&format=json
# Results in null
{"query":{"count":0,"created":"2013-01-11T18:39:21Z","lang":"en-US","results":null}}
```