# How to find Latitude and longitude of a location by its name in c#?

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, geolocation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Web service to get the GPS Coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1320262/web-service-to-get-the-gps-coordinates)

I'm using c# and i need to find the Latitude and Longitude of a location by it's name.
For example :

```
Tuple<double, double> lat_log = FindByLocation("England", "London");
```

I wonder if there is any web service for such thing! because i do not have and dictionary of locations or any database for it.

Comment: Latitude and Longitude can be very precise, London is a huge city - it has many valid lat & long combinations

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1320262/web-service-to-get-the-gps-coordinates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Description

Basicly there are many services who provide this information.

I suggest you use the

> **GoogleMaps.LocationServices 0.9.1 NuGet Package**
> A simple library for performing the a reverse geolocation lookups via Google Maps. This currently allows you to translate latitude / longitude to a region (state) and an address to a map point.
>
> **Install-Package GoogleMaps.LocationServices**

#### More Information

- [GoogleMaps.LocationServices 0.9.1](https://nuget.org/packages/GoogleMaps.LocationServices)

Answer (score 6):

Do an HTTP request for this URL:

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?sensor=false&address=London,England
```

and you'll get an XML document back with loads of information including the latitude and longitude.

Comment: You can also get JSON back if that's your thing (http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false&address=London,England). It is also good to note that google limits the number of requests to 2,500 per day.