# Web Services Available to get the number of satellites visible to a given coordinates

Tags: web-services, satellite

Hi I want to know is there any web services or URLs available to get the number of visible satellites by passing longitudes and latitudes. I tried searching but could find a service to use as a desktop application. I want to use this service without the usage of GPS or GPRS. If any one knows a web service or a URL please let me know it.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best web service to get satellites is [Heavens-above](http://www.heavens-above.com/), however, I'm not sure how you could get their database by yourself.

Aside from that, there are a few options:

1. You can download TLEs (Basically, the data required to calulate satellite positions) from [Celestrack](https://celestrak.org/NORAD/elements/), and find a library to calculate the satellites overhead from your position.
2. You can get the GPS coordinates from a web service easily enough. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1320262/544198).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can look into this [GNSS-Radar](http://www.taroz.net/GNSS-Radar.html)

It is a web application to show the current GNSS constellation at a specified location.

Here is the source code ([Github](https://github.com/taroz/GNSS-Radar)) of this web application. You can find the APIs provided and the source code of the application.